# How to set an attribute on a v-select option?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Just starting with Vue and need some advice on best practices.

What I'm trying to achieve: set `makeId` equal to the makes option id, based on what option is selected. So, for example, when I select "bmw" from the dropdown, I want `makeId` to equal 2.

Without Vuetify, I cloud set a data attribute to each option during the `v-for` loop, and then `@change` just grab that attribute and assign the value to the `makeid`.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do with Vuetify?

```html
<v-select v-model="car.make" :items="makes" item-value="name" item-text="name"> </v-select>
```

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    car: { make: "", makeId: "" },
    makes: [{ name: "audi", id: "1" }, { name: "bmw", id: "2" }]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

you can bind the `id` as the `item-value` and on the `v-model` you need to assign `car.madeId`instead of `car.make` if you need a single value:

```js
<v-select v-model="car.makeId" :items="makes" item-value="id" item-text="name"> </v-select>
```

**Or** you can use an extra method for object binding :

here is a fork for it: [codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/gVBxqd?editors=1011)

Comment: This leaves car.make unassigned, I need to set both car.make and car.makeid on selecting an option

Comment: @goddas im afraid that's not possible with `v-model` since it doesn't support object binding but i updated answer with a way that will solve the issue

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up using the function

Answer (score 1):

The main difficulty here is that you've got two different formats for your objects. Having to map between `id`/`name` and `make`/`makeId` complicates things.

This would be easy without the property mapping, you could just set `return-object` on the `v-select`.

Assuming that isn't possible, one alternative would be to have `car` as a computed property based on the selected value to perform the property renaming. This would look like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

  data () {
    return {
      selectedCar: null,
      makes: [{name: 'audi', id: '1'}, {name: 'bmw', id: '2'}]
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    car () {
      const selectedCar = this.selectedCar
      
      if (selectedCar) {
        return {
          make: selectedCar.name,
          makeId: selectedCar.id
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/mdi@2.2.43/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <p>{{ car }}</p>
    <v-select v-model="selectedCar" :items="makes" item-value="name" item-text="name" return-object> </v-select>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

We could instead flip around the relationship between `car` and `selectedCar` so that `car` is in `data` and `selectedCar` is the computed property. For that we'd need to implement a getter and a setter:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

  data () {
    return {
      car: {make: '', makeId: ''},
      makes: [{name: 'audi', id: '1'}, {name: 'bmw', id: '2'}]
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    selectedCar: {
      get () {
        return this.makes.find(make => make.id === this.car.makeId)
      },
      set (selectedCar) {
        this.car = {
          make: selectedCar.name,
          makeId: selectedCar.id
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/mdi@2.2.43/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <p>{{ car }}</p>
    <v-select v-model="selectedCar" :items="makes" item-value="name" item-text="name" return-object> </v-select>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

A third alternative is to ditch `v-model` altogether and just use the `:value`/`@input` pair directly:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

  data () {
    return {
      car: {make: '', makeId: ''},
      makes: [{name: 'audi', id: '1'}, {name: 'bmw', id: '2'}]
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    onInput (id) {
      const make = this.makes.find(make => make.id === id)
      
      this.car = {
        make: make.name,
        makeId: make.id
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/mdi@2.2.43/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <p>{{ car }}</p>
    <v-select :value="car.makeId" :items="makes" item-value="id" item-text="name" @input="onInput"> </v-select>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm just getting started with Vue, so it is all very helpful. I ended up using the solution from the previous comment simply because it takes a bit less code :)